# What is the 26-pin D-sub (DA-26) connector used for on the Media Vision Pro AudioSpectrum 16 Patch Panel?

Tags: identify-this-computer, audio, connector

My dad has this audio interface from the 90s called the Media Vision Pro AudioSpectrum 16 Patch Panel, but unfortunately doesn't have the manual. From my research, it appears that this panel was used to interface with the sound card of the same name in old Apple computers (which my dad owned in the 90s). The function is clear for every port on it except this one, which is on the side and appears to be intended to connect to the computer itself. However, the Pro AudioSpectrum sound card doesn't appear to have a DA-26 port! I can't find any helpful information about this patch panel or any relevant use for a DA-26 connector. I've attached an image and I'd be grateful if anyone could provide any relevant information. Thanks!

[image: Media Vision Pro AudioSpectrum 16 Patch Panel DA-26 plus cable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...]Media Vision Pro AudioSpectrum 16 Patch Panel [...] it appears that this panel was used to interface with the sound card of the same name in old Apple computers
>
> [...] The function is clear for every port on it except this one, which is on the side and appears to be intended to connect to the computer itself.

Not the computer but the sound card.

> However, the Pro AudioSpectrum sound card doesn't appear to have a DA-26 port!

Maybe you look at the wrong card?

[image: Pro AudioSpectrum 16 for the PC]

There was a [Pro AudioSpectrum 16](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E2QMYU6) for the PC and one for the Mac. The PC version (above) was a 16 Bit ISA card featuring an internal CD-ROM interface, as well as external connectors for audio signals and a joystick. It didn't use a patch panel.

[image: Pro AudioSpectrum 16 for the Apple Mac]

The Apple card (above) instead was a NUBUS card made to work with Mac II and Quadra models. It featured a single connector to attach the patch panel.

So, if you/your father have disposed the Mac with the card, the patch box did become rather useless.

Comment: Great, thank you! If he does still have the sound card, then would it still be usable? Not in a modern computer, I assume?

Comment: Nop. Apple droped NUBUS with the second Generation of PowerMacs around 1996 (IIRC). But hey, end of line 68k machines are more fun anyway :))